# Next() в Express

Tags: node.js, express

После очередного перечитывания документации Express. В мою голову так и не пришло понимание функции `next()`. Прошу вас объяснить мне. Для чего и в каких случаях нужно использовать `next()`, что эта функция возвращает? Давайте разберем на простом примере

```
app.get('/users/:id?', function(req, res, next) {
     var id = req.params.id;
     if (id) {
        // делаем что-то
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Что делает в данном случае `next()`

Comment: м? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695629/node-js-express-next

Comment: 1. Если при обработке запроса app.get("/users/:id",func,function(req,res,next){})передать ф-ю func, то в ней можно обрабатывать req и res. 2. в next() можно передать ф-ю в качестве аргумента next(User(req,res)) и внутри ф-ии обработать res 3. Есть ли еще варианты использования next()?
А вот когда указывают app.use(function(req,res,next){.... next()})?

Comment: отличное описание здесь http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Xp9yj3UIAg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 15):

Фреймворк Express.js построен на концепции ПО промежуточного уровня (англ. middleware). Суть этого подхода в том, что запрос к каждому ресурсу обрабатывается не одним единственным действием контролера (специально опускаю возможные препроцессоры и прочее), а целым **стеком** функций.

При этом, каждая из этих функций может каким-то образом изменять запрос/ответ и передавать управление следующей функции. Так же, какая-то из функций может сгенерировать конечный ответ и отдать его пользователю, прекращая, тем самым, движение вниз по стеку ПО промежуточного уровня.

Связывание элементов ПО промежуточного уровня в Express как раз и осуществляется с помощью функции `next`. Эта функция может быть использована для двух целей:

1. Передать управление следующей функции в стеке (для этого ф-ция `next` вызывается **без параметров**).
2. Сообщить фреймворку об ошибке и передать управление специализированному ПО промежуточного уровня (для этого функции `next` передается **объект ошибки**).

Если же функция `next` **не вызывается**, то это значит, что движение вниз по стеку функций должно быть закончено.

Проиллюстрирую все вышесказанное на примере. Типичное приложение на node.js с использованием Express выглядит следующим образом:

```js
var app = require('express')();

// Здесь мы будет добавлять к каждому входящему запросу время,
// когда он поступил с точностью до миллисекунд. В реальном
// приложении здесь может быть код инициализации сессии,
// аутентификации, авторизации или чего-то еще.
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    req.initTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    // Обратите внимание, функция "next" вызывается БЕЗ ПАРАМЕТРОВ.
    // Это позволяет предать управление следующему обработчику.
    next();
});
```

```js
// Этот обработчик проверяет время, инициализации запроса и,
// если количество миллисекунд четное, то он завершается с ошибкой.
// В реальных приложениях, это может быть, например, ошибка
// соединения с базой данных.
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.initTimestamp % 2 === 0) {
        // Обратите внимание, функции "next" передается ОБЪЕКТ ОШИБКИ.
        // Он будет использован чуть позже.
        next(new Error('Not today. Sorry.'));
    } else {
        // Просто отдаем ответ клиенту. Вызов "next" здесь НЕ НУЖЕН,
        // все следующие обработчики будут проигнорированы.
        res.send('The sun is shining. Have a nice day :)');
    }
});
```

```js
// А вот здесь мы обрабатываем все те ошибки, что были переданы
// как аргументы в функцию "next". Обратите внимание, у обработчика
// ЧЕТЫРЕ аргумента. "err" - это тот самый объект ошибки из
// предыдущего обработчика.
app.use('/', function(err, req, res, next) {
    // Просто отправляем сообщение об ошибке клиенту.
    res.send(err.message);
    // А вместо этого мы вполне могли бы передать управление
    // СЛЕДУЮЩЕМУ обработчику ошибок, вот так
    // next(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В этом видео понятное объяснение https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZX3qt0UWifc
Суть в том, что next() вызывает следующую функцию, если их в запросе несколько, а не одна. Например вот тут

```
app.get('/users', paginatedResults(users), (req, res) => { 
    res.json(res.paginatedResults);
});
```

посередине вставлена функция `paginatedResults(users)`, внутри которой должен быть `next()` иначе код следующий функции `(req, res) =>` не запустится

```
function paginatedResults(model) {
    ...
        next();
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если функция не отправляет `response`, то должна передать дальше по очереди управление.
То есть, должно быть либо `res`, либо `next`, иначё может всё зависнуть.