# Вызвать express js api метод внутри другого метода

Tags: rest, express

Есть некие rest api методы

например:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function method1 (res, req) {
    // something actions
}

router.get('/method1', method1);  

// вот решение
router.get('/method2', function(res, req) {
     req.data = { hand:'1' };
     return method1(res, req);
});
```

Вот таким образом можно переопределить и вызвать другой метод api, мне кажется это костыльный способ и плохо тестируемый. Очень часто возникает потребность переопределить или расширить определенный метод в API.
 насколько правильный такой способ?

Существует ли более надежная практика?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express.js построен на базе концепции ПО промежуточного уровня (англ. middleware).

Основная идея состоит в том, что каждый запрос обрабатывается не одной функцией-контроллером, а сразу целым стеком функций. Это позволяет вам "подготовить" объект запроса перед его непосредственной обработкой. Именно так работает, например, [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express();

app.post('/api', bodyParser.json());
app.post('/api/users', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Roger that!');
});
```

В вашем случае, можно использовать аналогичный подход:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

var method1 = function(req, res) {
    // ...
}

var preprocessor = function(req, res, next) {
    req.data = { hand:'1' };
    next();
}

router.get('/method1', method1);  
router.get('/method2', preprocessor);
router.get('/method2', method1);
```

Подробнее о том, как именно работать с аргументом `next` можно почитать [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267210/next-%D0%B2-express/450171#450171).

Comment: Спасибо за обширный ответ, я знал про мидлвери давно, просто парадигма мышления осталась закоренелая после php )

Comment: В php middleware тоже есть, например в Silex.

Answer (score 0):

Более правильным вариантом будет выделение общего кода в отдельную функцию/модуль и описать ее/его параметры более точно, а не использовать объекты запрос и ответ. То есть отделить логику вашего сервиса от транспорта (http).

Это позволит лучше выразить ваши намерения, улучшить модульность и облегчить тестирование.